# Why does adding a parent View Tag in React Native change the style?

Tags: ios, css, reactjs, react-native, view

Adding a `View` parent breaks my styles, why is this happening? Does React Native's `View` tag have some default styles that I'm unaware of?

Below is the Button component as well as a screenshot with and without the View Tag.

```
class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hello</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    color: "#007aff",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "600",
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#007aff",
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
  }
});
```

[image: With View Tag]

[image: Without View Tag]

The button is being rendered inside another component(A typical card component), if need I can provide that code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, your `TouchableOpacity` has all of your container styles, and this is going to cause the weird issue you are seeing. By defining `flex:1`, it means it will stretch itself to fill the area of the parent view. However, your parent view has not been flexed, so it will only fill the space that it needs to. It will however put your text component in however it seems fit, hence the weird result you are getting.

To debug this, I often will set `backgroundColor: 'red'`, to see what flexbox is doing. In your case, i don't see the need for a parent view ? `TouchableOpacity` is simply an extension of view, so you should be able to do all your styling in it. If you are wanting to add a view though, i'd suggest wrapping it with your `Touchable` - otherwise you have the risk of messing up your `onPress`s. Something like

```
render() {
return (
  <View style = {{height: 100, shadowColor: 'black', shadowRadius: 3}}> //RANDOM CARD CODE


    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}>
      <View> //ANY STYLES HERE
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>


  </View>
)};
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for responding late. I had to put the project on hold for little. The reason I want to wrap it with a View is because I'm trying to create my own Radio Buttons. I was hopping to group x-many buttons together in a View

Comment: the code ive provided should still work (note its an example `Button` render function, you can simply have a column of these as you wish inside your parent view)